# Using Same Delegate Signature for Parameter and Parameterless Method

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a method which takes method delegate having parameter

```
 public delegate void RunOperation(object o );
  public void Abort(RunOperation operationToRun, object obj)
  {
  }
  public void AllMessages()
  {
  }
```

Is it possible to pass AllMessage() as a delegate to Abort() ?

I don't want to create any new delgate for parameterless methods.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747948/c-sharp-how-can-i-overload-a-delegate

Answer (score 2):

No and Yes.

You can like this:

```
Abort(_ => AllMessages(), null);
```

But you're just creating another method that calls `AllMessages` and doesn't use the object parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it in this way:

```
public void Abort(Action operationToRun, object obj)
{

}
public void Abort(Action<object> operationToRun, object obj)
{

}
public void AllMessages()
{

}
```

**Explanation**:

Make an overload for the Abort method. First method takes an action without parameter and second takes an action with one parameter. So you can call Abort with a parameterless method and a method with an object parameter.