# Generic Delegate Duplicate Definition - Why?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have two generic delegates that I am atttempting to define that the compiler is complaining that they are duplicates, but to my eye are completely different.  What am I doing/understanding wrong?

```
delegate TReturn foo<TParameter, out TReturn>(TParameter parameter, IItem item);
```

and

```
delegate TReturn foo<TParameter, out TReturn>(TParameter parameter, int field, IItem item);
```

If I add a new generic parameter to the second delegate, everything works.

```
delegate TReturn foo<TParameter, TField, out TReturn>(TParameter parameter, TField field, IItem item) where TField struct
```

but that is does not appear to be correct.  I will always be passing an int for field - it should not be a generic.

Comment: What is the exact compile error?

Comment: The error is "The namespace 'xxx' already contains a definition for 'foo'". It kind of makes sense but I can't really explain it.

Comment: i think you can simplify the question by removing the generics here. Lets say you have two delegates: `delegate void f()` and `delegate void f(int)`, and then you got a delegate object: `f a;`, you will have no idea which version of the delegate from which this object is instantiated. It's not safe to call either `a()` of `a(1)` because you don't know whether the delegate object actually represents a method with 0 or 1 argument. Therefore delegates are not like methods that can be overloaded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegates are not methods.  They know how to call a method, but they themselves are not methods (a delegate is an `object`) and can therefore not be overloaded like a method.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747948/c-sharp-how-can-i-overload-a-delegate) for an explanation of why it cannot be possible.

Answer (score 3):

When using `delegate` keyword, what happens behind the scenes is that the compiler generates a class based on its definition. So when you define a delegate like this:

```
delegate TReturn foo<TParameter, out TReturn>(TParameter parameter, IItem item);
```

a following class is generated from it:

```
class foo<TParameter, out TReturn> : MulticastDelegate
{
    public void Invoke(TParameter parameter, IItem item) { ... }
    ....
}
```

As you can see, when you have two delegates with the same name and same generic parameters, it results in generation of two identical classes, which is, of course, not acceptable.

I recommend an excellent book [CLR via C#](https://books.google.com/books/about/CLR_Via_C.html?id=7yb-QQAACAAJ) from Jeffrey Richter that sheds more light on behind-the-scenes stuff like this - and much more.