# How to not specify the data type of arguments?

Tags: c#

I want an `Adapter` like function. The parent class want `DataTable`, while its derived class may pass in anything. I'm now setting the data type to `object` and then cast it. But I do not think this is pretty.

```
class Parent
{
    protected void Add(DataTable dt) { ... }        // the real business logics
    public virtual void AddRaw(object anything) {}
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
    public override void AddRaw(object anything)
    {
        MyTable1 t = (MyTable1) anything;

        // pseudo code
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach(row r in t)
        {
            dt.AddRow(r);
        }

        this.Add(dt);
    }
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    public override void AddRaw(object anything)
    {
        MyTable2 t = (MyTable2) anything;
        ...
    }
}
```

I've background from `javascript` and `python`. It's so common to do such things in a "weak type" languages, and within which you can pass anything anywhere.

I've used `<T>` and `delegate` in `C#` before. But I cannot think of a way using them here.

What's the `C#` way of doing this?

Comment: void AddRaw(MyTable anything), what's wrong with this? Also, I suppose that Child derives from Parent?

Comment: @BlackBear I might have `MyTable2`, `MyTable3`

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Why not change `public virtual void AddRaw(MyTable anything) {}` in the base class? This probably should be an abstract method anyway, or not be there at all.

Comment: MyTable should have a common base though? BaseTable perhaps?

Comment: @JamesBarrass. No. That's the problem. MyTable can be ANYTHING.

Comment: But when it can be anything, why do you cast it to MyTable?

Comment: @hbrlovehaku _why_ can it be anything? you are explicitly casting it to a `MyTable1` so you must be pretty sure it's going to be a valid cast right?

Comment: Then MyTable cannot be enumerated or adapted, it must be something your adapter class can interpret, at the very least IEnumerable<Object>

Comment: @JamesBarrass: `IEnumerable` will do

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not restricted to `IEnumerable`. e.g. `int number; for i in range(0, number): dt.AddRow(i)`

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic` keyword, an interface implementation or abstract base class, but I would personally prefer using as much typed members as possible.

Use of `dynamic`:

```
public override void AddRaw(dynamic anything)
{
    // pseudo code
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach(row r in anything)
    {
        dt.AddRow(r);
    }

    this.Add(dt);
}
```

You can also do something like this, if you want to match anything and act based on the type:

```
public override void AddRaw(object anything)
{
    if (o is MyTable)
    { ... }
    else if (o is string)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `dynamic` was exactly what I was hoping to have. But the other answers provided alternatives. I have to think about which is the best answer.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: If inheritance is an option, use that. (please... your life will not get better using `dynamic`)

Comment: No, we're still discussing the requirements.

Comment: This answered the original question best. However, I've not made up my mind to use this `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

How about overloading your method?

```
class Parent
{
    protected void Add(DataTable dt) { ... }
}

class Child1:Parent
{
    public void Add(MyTable1 anything)
    {
        // pseudo code
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach(row r in anything)
        {
            dt.AddRow(r);
        }

        this.Add(dt);
    }
}

class Child2:Parent
{
    public void Add(MyTable2 anything)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I may want to use delegate in the future. I'm not sure if `overloading` is OK with that.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku based on [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/533114-delegates-overloaded-methods) it should be OK

Comment: @hbrlovehaku [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747953/1993545) is also an example how you could use a delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent class generic:

```
class Parent<T>
{
    protected void Add(DataTable dt) { ... }        // the real business logics
    public virtual void AddRaw(T anything) {}
}

class Child1 : Parent<MyTable1>
{
    public override void AddRaw(MyTable1 anything) { ... }
}

class Child2 : Parent<MyTable2>
{
    public override void AddRaw(MyTable2 anything) { ... }
}
```

In addition, I'd suggest to make `Parent` abstract, unless you really need to create `Parent` instances:

```
abstract class Parent<T>
{
    protected void Add(DataTable dt) { ... }        // the real business logics
    public abstract void AddRaw(T anything);
}
```

That way, the compiler ensures that every client *must* implement `AddRaw`.

Comment: You suggestion seems the most elegant. But I still have a question. What if I want to `Child : Parent<DataTable>`, `GrandChild : Child <List>`?

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: You can't. And you don't want to. Please explain in plain English what this would mean. You can't...

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use an adapter resolver class. Create each adapter in their own class and register them with a static class along with the type they adapter

```
Adapters.Register(typeof(MyTable), MyTableAdapter)
```

or
//  void Register(Adapter) and MyTableAdapter: Adapter
    Adapters.Register(MyTableAdapter)

then you'd request an adapter from the the Adapters list

```
Adapters.GetAdapter<MyTable>();
```

where you could return a sensible error if no adapters for that type had been registered