# Overload VB.NET event?

Tags: vb.net, class

In my VB.NET class I have some code like this:

```
Public Class barClass

Private Function foo(data as string)
    msgbox("Data is a string: " & data)
End Function

Private Function foo(data as integer)
    msgbox("Data is an integer: " & data
End Function

End Class
```

Which obviously lets you pass `foo` a string or integer.

I figured I could do the same for events, so I try:

```
Public Event FooRaised(data as string)
Public Event FooRaised(data as integer)
```

Which I assume would let me raise the event by passing it whatever data I get from `foo` but I get an error, saying I can't do that (that FooRaised has already been declared).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: How would handlers to such an event work?

Comment: You cannot overload events - simple as that.

Comment: Events have a specific declaration, and you can't just invent new ones as you go randomly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - How can I "overload" a delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747948/c-sharp-how-can-i-overload-a-delegate)

Comment: Events are generally designed to be less ambiguous about what is happening.  In the end nothing much is saved because something somewhere has to use an `If` to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a single event using an Object parameter, then check the type to process it:

```
Public Class Form1

  Public Event Foo(o As Object)

  Sub FooHandler(o As Object) Handles Me.Foo
    If o.GetType Is GetType(Integer) Then
      Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(o, Integer)
      i += 1 'add one to the integer value'
      MsgBox(i.ToString)
    ElseIf o.GetType Is GetType(String) Then
      Dim s As String = DirectCast(o, String)
      s &= "!!" 'append exclamation marks'
      MsgBox(s)
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent Foo(21)
    RaiseEvent Foo("a string value")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If it isn't obvious, I added one and appended exclamation marks to show how to convert the Object back into the original variable type and use the variable.

Comment: A sub with an object type was where I was heading next, but I wasn't sure if there was a better way to go about it. Thanks for the answer!